# How do I cancel a half-way commit in svn?

Tags: svn, commit

I've edited some files, and accidentally ran `svn ci` in the trunk, where really what I wanted to do is to run `svn ci` in a subdirectory. SVN says I have conflicts in another directory where I don't actually want to commit yet. So I go to the correct subdirectory to run `svn ci` and there is nothing to commit, which means that I have a half-way commit.
Now I want to cancel this half-way commit, while not losing my changes in both directories, and then commit in the correct subdirectory. How should this be done?

Comment: Have you tried a **svn cleanup** in the trunk?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to do a reverse merge.

Perhaps this is what you want. 
http://markphip.blogspot.com/2007/01/how-to-undo-commit-in-subversion.html
Also see 
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html